# manipulating data with Stored Procedure, transaction using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have 3 stored procedures on 3 different tables.. whose main purpose is to insert,delete,view and update.

i have a signup form which contains 9 fields which needs to be filled by the user. once the user clicks submit the first 3 field data will be sent to first SP,next 3 to second SP, and last 3 to third SP.

I'm looking out to implement transactions to do it.. so that if all the data is added successfully its commit or else the whole data should be rolled back.

```
string connectionString =
WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Northwind"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(con, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "usp_additemdata",      p);
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(con, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "usp_addpricedata", p)
SqlTransaction tran = null;
try
{

con.Open();

cmd1.Transaction = tran;
cmd2.Transaction = tran;

cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
Commit the transaction.
tran.Commit();
 }
catch
{

 tran.Rollback();
}
finally
{
con.Close();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you are facing problem in the code written we could help you fixing it but not writing the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Transaction Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) here

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(yourconnectionstring))
        {
           //your commands here
        }

        // The Complete method commits the transaction. If an exception has been thrown,
        // Complete is not  called and the transaction is rolled back.
        scope.Complete();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection("ConnectionStringHere");
      SqlTransaction transaction;

  db.Open();
  transaction = db.BeginTransaction();
  try 
  {
    var SqlC1= new SqlCommand("SP1", db, transaction);
    <Add parameters in SqlC1>
        SqlC1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    var SqlC2= new SqlCommand("SP2", db, transaction);
    <Add parameters in SqlC2>
        SqlC2.ExecuteNonQuery();

     var SqlC3= new SqlCommand("SP3", db, transaction);
    <Add parameters in SqlC3>
        SqlC3.ExecuteNonQuery();
     transaction.Commit();
  } 
  catch (SqlException sqlError) 
  {
     transaction.Rollback();
  }
  db.Close();**strong text**
```

Comment: Thank you for the solutions.. it worked for me but a small addition to the code is needed to execute SP..
1)    var SqlC1= new SqlCommand("SP1", db, transaction);
2)<<<sqlC1.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure >>>>
3)    <Add parameters in SqlC1>
4)        SqlC1.ExecuteNonQuery();

With 2nd statement the code didnt work... but it work fine if the sql query is directly passed

Comment: im new to posting.. do u want me to post as answer or .. as comment.. ?